# ¿Es posible colocar etiquetas de schema.org en páginas web dinámicas?

Tags: web, google-visualization

Tengo mi sitio web funcionando y con etiquetas del tipo meta, con los datos básicos como nombre del sitio, descripción y autor, con el fin de que aparezca mi sitio en buscadores como Google, Bing, etc. El caso es que, tengo entendido que se le puede meter al sitio datos estructurados, de manera tal que optimice la presencia del sitio web en los buscadores, tanto Google como algún otro.

Mi sitio tiene una sección el cual son páginas dinámicas, y al hacer pruebas con la herramienta de prueba de datos estructurados de Google, noté que tengo dudas con respecto al código generado por la herramienta; pues dicha sección de mi web sirve contenido dinámico, más o menos del tipo `página.php?id=12`.

Tengo mis dudas respecto a este tema de los datos estructurados. Y mi pregunta es si es posible aplicar las etiquetas de schema.org entre las páginas dinámicas de mi web, y si el código que la herramienta de Google me genera es igualmente válida para aplicar en esta sección de mi web. Todo esto sin provocar una penalización por parte del buscador.

Sin más por el momento, eso es todo. Saludos y buen día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no hay ningún problema.
Esta URL (página.php?id=12), aunque sea una query no rankea en los buscadores por ser estática o dinámica. Cuando llega el crawler de google se "lleva datos" de esa URL (título,keywords,contenido,datos estructurados, etc).

Cuando el buscador presenta tu página entre los resultados muestra en primer lugar el título, en la segunda línea la URL y luego un extracto del contenido.

El algoritmo de google sabe que esta URL integra schemas, por lo cual gana puntos, se haya generado vía tradicional o vía script.

Otra cosa es que si sería bueno que integrases urls amigables.
No es lo mismo una url del tipo (página.php?id=12), que otra del tipo (página.php/contacto).
Esto lo puedes cambiar fácilmente dependiendo de tu configuración (wordpress,apache,etc).

Salu2

Comment: Ok. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Voy a implementarlo entonces. Y en cuanto lo de las urls amigables, ya lo acabo de implementar. Saludos.